# jQuery libraries conflict with different jquery versions

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, conflicting-libraries, revolution-slider

I am redesigning my website with a template I have downloaded preiously (which is [this one](http://titanicthemes.com/demo/travel/blue/index7.html)).
My old website is [this](http://www.aeleisure.com) and the new one is located in another [folder](http://www.aeleisure.com/new/).
Obviously Im trying to use most of the functionality made previously in the new design to save some time.

The template has many libraries and I need to use different versions of jquery

- jquery 2.0.3 (for most of the page)
- jquery 1.8.3 (for the autocomplete plugin, which is not the one from jquery ui).

I have tried the noConflict() function of jquery and I still cannot solve it.
The file 'assets/js/js-home.js' was previously in the template.
I don't know what else to do. 
Some help of you guys will be appreciated.
If you guys need some extra information, let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find a version that everything runs smoothly with.

First could try just using the `2.0.3` version, loaded before all plugins.

If that causes any errors to be thrown, you can install the [migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) to see what code might be causing issues. It has a lot of the deprecated methods in it and logs warnings when those methods get used to help you see what is outdated.

Another option is using the latest 1.xx series (latest is 1.11.2) which still has support for older browsers in it. The 1.xx series is still maintained.

For a new upgrade on your site it would be unfortunate to need to load 
2 different versions.

to simplify testing you can find every version of jQuery on their [CDN](http://code.jquery.com/) so all you have to do is switch `src` in script tags to switch.

Answer (score -1):

```
jq214 = jQuery.noConflict( true );
```